# What does these plus sign after equal sign mean in formula bar

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In one excel inside the formula bar there is a plus sign after = sign in different cells which are calculating different types of performance on a dollar value for historical months. All i want to ask is what is this + sign mean . Below are three examples.

1. `=+O6*(1+B7)`
2. `=+EY203*(1+'Product Performance Monthly'!J261)`
3. `{=+PRODUCT(1+FA$208:FA209)-1}`

Comment: A good read: https://www.quora.com/What-does-a-plus-sign-mean-in-an-Excel-formula

Comment: Since there is now a good signpost to an answer which reinforces the main message - that it does *nothing*, I've delete my answer

Answer (score 3):

The plus sign is significant only if the content of the cell does *not* start with `=`. It that case it makes the text a formula.

If you type `A1+B1`, it's just a string. But `+A1+B1` is a formula.

But if you write e.g. `+A1+B1` and leave the cell, Excel will automatically add the `=` in front of it but leaves there the `+` sign. That's one of the reasons why you may get an Excel sheet with this weird start characters. Of course another reason might be that someone might have wanted to emphasize the positive value.

A very unpleasant side effect of this is that typing phone numbers in international format (`+44123456789`) is a pain - you have to either prefix each text with `'` character (`'+44123456789`, the `'` is a marker character for plain text) or explicitly mark the format of the cell as `text'.

Comment: Plus, as used here, is a holdover from the days of Lotus 1-2-3.

Comment: Great! Thank you for a very quick response, and well explaination . I understand it fully now. Thank you :)\

Comment: @Drake: the best way of saying *thank you* is by accepting the answer :)